# Ignored duplicate property derby.module.dataDictionary in Hive

Tags: hive, data-partitioning

I have an EMPLOYEES table which is partitioned on the basis of COUNTRY and STATE. Below are the partitions.

```
hive (human_resources)> show partitions employees ;
OK
country=IN/state=PU
country=US/state=CA
country=US/state=IL
Time taken: 0.119 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

I loaded data in these partitions from local file system.

When I execute **SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE STATE = 'IL' ;**, the output is shown after these lines

**Thread[main   5.0 ["main] Ignored duplicate property derby.module.dataDictionary in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar!/org/apache/derby/modules.properties"]  NULL    NULL    US  IL**

**Thread[main   5.0 ["main] \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"]    NULL    NULL    US  IL
----------------------------------------------------------------    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    US  IL**

I do not get these messages when I query the table on the other two partitions. Please let me know how to get rid of these messages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE country ='US' and state ='IL'` and let me know if it is works, if not can you post partial of your data and your table metadata

`